# Turn off duplicate outputs to console.log() in karma

Tags: automated-tests, phantomjs, karma-runner

When running tests with phantomjs I have console messages logged twice like:

> PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 8) LOG: 'myNavigation loading...'
>
> LOG: 'myNavigation loading...'

But when running in chrome my output is like:

> Chrome 37.0.2062 (Windows 8.1) LOG: 'myNavigation loading...'.

(no duplicate logging here)

I guess second log is coming from dots reporter, so is there an opportunity to easily turn off second console output so that only browsers could do logging?

Here is part of my karma config:

```
reporters: ['trx', 'dots'],
browsers: ['PhantomJS', 'Chrome'],
```